# Add ClickHandler to every button

Tags: gwt, event-handling

I am trying to implement a click logging system in GWT, so I know where people are going around my app.

I want to be able to do this automatically with out adding the handler to every single Button?

I tried in a `Composite` class:

```
this.addDomHandler(new ClickHandler() {...}, ClickEvent.getType());
```

But the `ClickEvent` didn't give me any specifics on what had been clicked. The below didn't work as well.

```
    NodeList<Element> elements = Document.get().getElementsByTagName("a");

    EventListener el = new EventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onBrowserEvent(Event event) {
            System.out.println(event.toString());
        }
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < elements.getLength(); i++) {
        Element e = elements.getItem(i);
        com.google.gwt.user.client.Element castedElem = (com.google.gwt.user.client.Element) e;
        DOM.sinkEvents(castedElem, Event.ONCLICK);
        DOM.setEventListener(castedElem, el);
    }
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look here:

[Notice every click in a gwt application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20222261/notice-every-click-in-a-gwt-application/20222773#20222773)

This will be called on every click in your applilcation.

So, if you have this code:

```
Event.addNativePreviewHandler(new NativePreviewHandler() { 
      @Override 
      public void onPreviewNativeEvent(NativePreviewEvent event) {
        if (event.getNativeEvent().getType().equals("click")) { 
            Element eventTarget = DOM.eventGetTarget(Event.as(event.getNativeEvent()));
          // check if eventTarget is an a-tag 
        } 
      }
    });
```

Any time the mouse is clicked, you will get an event. Exame the event to see, if an a-tag is clicked.

Hope that helps.